# The method .fit() of a Sklearn Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Does a Sklearn model's .fit () method reset the weights on each call? Does the pice of code below its all right? I saw it somewhere for cross validation and I dont know if it makes sense.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200)
regr = MLPRegressor(solver='sgd', max_iter=150)

for i in range(5):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
    regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it resets the weights, as you can see here on the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#refitting-and-updating-parameters)

> Calling fit() more than once will overwrite what was learned by any previous fit()

Comment: @Douglas Oliveira Happy to help! If it solved your issue, mark it as the anwer, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers